# Traversing List C#

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, soundplayer, piano

I am playing around with some C# and I was coding a piano application.

Whenever the user clicks a piano note, I am storing the location of the sound (.wav) into a list... the following is some code in the button1_MouseDown method.

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
   {
       SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer();
       string musName = Convert.ToString(mk.pitch);
       string loc = @"D:\OneDrive\Year 2 Semester 1\OOP\Notes-Sound files\Notes-Sound files\mapped\" + musName + ".wav";
       sp.SoundLocation = loc;
       sp.Play();
       music.Add(loc);
    }
```

Now, I want to traverse the loop to play all the clicked keys at one go. I am doing this as follows (when user clicks on the play button)

```
int k = 0;
for (k = 1; k < music.Count; k++)
{
   SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer();
   sp.SoundLocation = music[k];
   sp.Play();
 }
```

The thing is, that whenever the play button is clicked only the last note pressed is played.However, when I debug, somehow, all the notes are played. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I think that you have to wait that each note is played before playing the next one

Comment: I also assume yo won´t need to intialize a new player within every single iteration, but outside the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.play(v=vs.110).aspx), this is the description of the `Play` method:

> Plays the .wav file using a new thread, and loads the .wav file first if it has not been loaded.

So whenever you invoke `Play`, it's runs asynchronously and your loop continues to execute playing the next wav file before the current one is completed. When you debug, you are probably waiting anyways before proceeding in the loop.

Instead, try using [`PlaySync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playsync(v=vs.110).aspx) to play the sound synchronously

PS. Also, you might want to consider using the instances of `SoundPlayer` in your list instead of the filename to avoid creating new instances each time you play the wav file:

```
List<SoundPlayer> music = new List<SoundPlayer>();
//...

//In your first loop, you would add the SoundPlayer object
music.Add(sp);

//.. 
//Then when you're playing back:
for (int k = 0; k < music.Count; k++)
{
   music[k].PlaySync();
}
```

Note that the index in the `for` loop should start at 0 as well

Comment: @KMoussa

Where should I place 

'var music = new List<SoundPlayer>();'

Comment: @AxelAzzopardi in place of the `music` list/array of `strings` you're currently declaring

Comment: Wouldn't calling PlaySync on _different_ SoundPlayers, like in this example, cause it to actually run Asyncrously? How does music[1] know when music[0] is done playing? Isn't it better to just run one MusicPlayer and then change the SoundLocation in the loop and play synchrously?

Comment: @KMoussa An error occurred because var may only appear within a local variable declaration. I have 2 methods. If I place it in one method, the other method doesn't find it.

Comment: @AxelAzzopardi sorry my mistake, you can't use `var` for class members, try `List<SoundPlayer> music = new List<SoundPlayer>();` as a field in your class

Comment: @JerriKangasniemi I don't think whether `PlaySync` is called on the same instance or not would have any effect on whether it's sync or async, the sync method will not return control to the loop until the sound has played, so the loop will not continue before that. You might be correct performance-wise though, but I'm not sure

Comment: @KMoussa you legend

Comment: @AxelAzzopardi :)

Answer (score 0):

you may need to play the sound `Asynchronously` by using `LoadAsync` like here: [How to: Load a Sound Asynchronously within a Windows Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w50sk4c9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that the notes all play, but the subsequent notes actually start playing before the first one is done. Thus you hear just the last one.

Use [PlaySync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playsync(v=vs.110).aspx), which plays the sounds synchrously, and if you for some reason have to traverse the `List<>` and say, do a check on each item before playing (well, at least if you derive the SoundPlayer to another class so that it actually has things to check), you could use a check for the PlaySync call.

```
SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer();

foreach(var note in music)
{
    sp.SoundLocation = note;
    bool everythingIsFine = false;

    // Logic for everythingIsFine;

    if(everythingIsFine){
        sp.PlaySync(); 
    }
}
```